# org.json.XML.toJSONObjec(xmlString) converts a 010101 text value as a 4161decimal

Tags: java, xml, json

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><data><MatEiningaNumer>010101</MatEiningaNumer></data>
```

Java code:

```
String xmlString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><data><MatEiningaNumer>010101</MatEiningaNumer></data>";
JSONObject json = org.json.XML.toJSONObject(xmlString);
```

Resulting json:

```
data={"MatEiningaNumer":4161}
```

The problem is that the org.json.XML.toJSONObject(xmlString) method converts the 010101 text value as if it is a 8 base encoded decimal and the result is 4161

Is there a way to make this method not to converts the strings? 
To put only string values in the resulting json?

The only solution that I have in mind is to add some string prefix, let say "pre".
In order to make the converter believe it is a string.
Like this pre010101.
And in the Javascript file where the json is used to remove the prefix.

Is there another solution?

Comment: Have you tried adding quotes into the Java string? `<MatEiningaNumer>\"010101\"</MatEiningaNumer>`

Comment: No. It does not work.

Comment: What does your DTD say about `MatEiningaNumer`?  What type is expected?

Comment: There is no DTD. The XML is dynamically created in the Java code. The actual XML is more complex. But the type I want is String. Because it is not a real number. It may start with zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a way to tell JSON not to parse the input as a number, but to parse it as a string.  If you can't use the DTD and quote marks don't work, then you could try to fool the parser.  Add an extra character: `Z010101` to ensure that the input cannot be parsed as a number.  Then strip off the 'Z' by hand later.

Is there no other way to tell the parser to treat the input as a string?

Comment: I have used the approach with extra prefix you described. Because I found no other way to tell the parser not to convert it as a number. Thank you.